# TikZ fill behavior depends on perspective (tikz-3dplot)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{-5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=gray] (1.66, -2, 0) -- (1.33, -2, 0) .. controls (1.33, -0.5, -1) .. (1.33, 1, 0) -- (1.66, 1, 0) .. controls (1.66, -0.5, -1) .. (1.66, -2, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[fill=gray] (1.66, -2, 0) -- (1.33, -2, 0) .. controls (1.33, -0.5, -1) .. (1.33, 1, 0) -- (1.66, 1, 0) .. controls (1.66, -0.5, -1) .. (1.66, -2, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which outputs the following:

[image]

I'm drawing a curved sheet for which the interior should be filled in, but precisely how this is filled in depends on the coordinate system - the first one is how it should be shaded, but it seems like if I change the perspective, TikZ gets confused and doesn't shade it in properly. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: There are different filling rules. I don't know if switching to a different one would help in the second case? See 15.5.2 Graphic Parameters: Interior Rules in the manual, maybe?

Comment: Well, how would you like it to be filled in the second case? Everything inside the path is shaded, everything outside is not. Is this not the expected behavior?

Comment: @schtandard I would like it filled as though you were shading the actual interior of the 2D surface specified by the \draw command, embedded in 3D. I agree that if you just take the path and project it down to 2D, the filling is as expected. But I'm drawing a sheet in three-dimensional space and I would like the filling to take that into account.

Comment: @HenryShackleton I see. Well, Ti*k*Z does not really understand 3D space. The input of three coordinates is just some syntactic sugar that is converted to the 2D space of the picture _before_ any drawing or filling is performed, i.e. it is just a path coordinate transformation. If you want the appearance of 3D, you will have to calculate where to fill yourself (or use appropriate packages, though those are never very general). If you want true 3D, Ti*k*Z is not the right tool, have a look at Asymptote.